# Nokogiri method error

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I am using Nokogiri as a tool to help me with a project I'm working on for school. Right now the idea of the project is to search an HTML document for a keyword that the user provides. The function will find all occurrences of the keyword in the HTML string after the `<body>` element unless the keyword appears within an HTML tag, then surround the string found with tags to ``highlight’’ the keyword. Right now my code is failing with a pretty hefty error call stack. The main error is this: 
Nokogiri::CSS::SyntaxError:unexpected'$'after''[:substring_match,"simple"]'(Nokogiri::CSS::SyntaxError)

**My Current Method:**

```
require 'nokogiri'

file = File.open ("desktop/Personal/code.HTML")

@doc = Nokogiri::HTML(file)

puts @doc

puts "Welcome to the HTML keyword highlighter!"
puts "Please enter a keyword"
keyword = gets.chomp

highlight = "<span style='background-color: yellow; color: black'>#{keyword}</span>"

search = @doc.xpath("//body").search("[text()*=#{keyword}")

search.each do |node|
    nodeN = node.name
    nodeH = node.content.gsub(keyword, highlight)
    node.replace(nodeH)
end
file.close
```

**The error call stack:**

```
     /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2. 0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.5.6/lib/nokogiri/css/parser_extras.rb:87:in `on_error': unexpected '$' after '[:substring_match, "simple"]' (Nokogiri::CSS::SyntaxError)
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/racc/parser.rb:258:in `_racc_do_parse_c'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/racc/parser.rb:258:in `do_parse'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.5.6/lib/nokogiri/css/parser_extras.rb:62:in `parse'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.5.6/lib/nokogiri/css/parser_extras.rb:79:in `xpath_for'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.5.6/lib/nokogiri/css.rb:23:in `xpath_for'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.5.6/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:111:in `block (2 levels) in css'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.5.6/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:109:in `map'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.5.6/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:109:in `block in css'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.5.6/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:239:in `block in each'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.5.6/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:238:in `upto'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.5.6/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:238:in `each'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.5.6/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:105:in `css'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.5.6/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:81:in `block in search'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.5.6/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:80:in `each'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.5.6/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:80:in `search'
    from /Users/Eva/Desktop/Personal/Project_Nokogiri.rb:21:in `<main>'
```

Any advice on how to go about preventing this would be truly appreciated!  I'm new to programming, Ruby, and Nokogiri so I have very little understanding of how to fix this on my own. Sorry if formatting is bad. Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to close the square bracket:

```
search = @doc.xpath("//body").search("[text()*=#{keyword}]")
```

I'd add quotes just in case:

```
search = @doc.xpath("//body").search("[text()*=\"#{keyword}\"]")
```

(You might expand that by also ensuring the double quote is escaped if it is in `keyword` to make it bulletproof)

Comment: Oh thank you!! I would have looked at that for hours and never realized!! One last question if you don't mind. Right now the method changes the original HTML file how do I get it to instead make a new file and apply the changes to that file instead?

Comment: No, right now it does nothing of the sort: the document is changed, then the program exits, discarding the changes it has in the memory. To save, `File.write('newfile.xml', @doc.to_xml)`.